# Kotlin convert List to vararg

Tags: list, kotlin, variadic-functions

I have input data of type `List<UnitWithComponents>`

```
class UnitWithComponents {
    var unit: Unit? = null
    var components: List<Component> = ArrayList()
}
```

I want to convert the data to a `vararg` of `Unit`

Currently I am doing `*data.map { it.unit!! }.toTypedArray()`. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: would be easier to use `mapNotNull{}` to avoid some surprises or exceptions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's the correct way to do it (assuming you want to throw an exception when `it.unit` is `null` for some element of the list).

Answer (score 30):

```
fun foo(vararg strings: String) { /*...*/ }
```

#### Using

```
foo(strings = arrayOf("a", "b", "c"))

val list: MutableList<String> = listOf("a", "b", "c") as MutableList<String>
foo(strings = list.map { it }.toTypedArray())
```

---

> Named arguments are not allowed for non-Kotlin functions (*.java)

So, in this case you should replace:

From: `strings = list.map { it }.toTypedArray()`

To: `*list.map { it }.toTypedArray()`

GL

[Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

Comment: There is no need to use `as MutableList` here, and in some cases that will cause a crash because not all overloads of the `listOf` function in the standard library use MutableList under the hood.