# Kotlin. Vararg how to filter null values

Tags: kotlin, variadic-functions, kotlin-extension, kotlin-null-safety

I have an API that has method which takes vararg of some object (fox example Param).
I need to filter null params and not put it to vararg. Is it possible ?

I know there is a method in kotlin `listOfNotNull` but api accepts `vararg`(

This is example of calling API method (apiMethod(vararg params: Param)):

```
someFun() {
   apiMethod( 
      Param("first"),
      Param("second"),
      null // need to filter it
    )
}
```

P.S. I can't change `apiMethod()`

Comment: You can pass a `List` to a varargs. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51161558/5133585

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin convert List to vararg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161558/kotlin-convert-list-to-vararg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to filter your arguments before passing them to the function since you cannot modify the function. To do this, you can filter to a List, and then convert that list to a typed array and pass it using the `*` spread operator:

```
fun someFun() {
   apiMethod( 
      *listOfNotNull(
          Param("first"),
          Param("second"),
          null // need to filter it
      ).toTypedArray()
    )
}
```

It's a shame you have to use `toTypedArray()`. IMO, it should be supported for all Iterables, since Lists are far more common than Arrays. This [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12663) has not had a lot of attention from JetBrains.

Answer (score 0):

Your `apiMethod()` should fail either filter out nulls or just fail if provided list that contains null

```
fun apiMethod(a : Int, b : String, vararg params : List<Any?>){
   require(params.size == params.mapNotNull { it }.size) {
        "Params must not contain null values"
   }
   // or 
   val filtered = params.mapNotNull { it } 
  
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `filterNotNull()` be simpler than `mapNotNull{ it }`? (Note: `…Not…`, not `…Non…`.)

Comment: The final result is the same. (I made a mistake about not and non)

Comment: Same result, less readable code, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapNotNull method

```
 val notNullArgs = args.mapNotNull { it }
```

If there will be any null `it` it will be filtered